# $Z_N$ one-form symmetry of $SU(N)$ super Yang-Mills

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

In Gaiotto's paper "[Generalized Global Symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148)", a paragraph above (1.3) states a fact about the one-form symmetry of a gauge field:

> we start with a gauge theory based on a simply connected gauge group $G$ and assume that there are no matter fields transforming under $Γ$, a subgroup of the center of $G$. Then the system has $\Gamma$ one-form global symmetry

I don't find this very obvious. Let me break it down into two questions.

(1) If there is no matter at all, then how to derive/see explicitly, for example, the $Z_N$ one-form symmetry of an $SU(N)$ gauge theory?

(2) Suppose there is some matter. **Why should the one-form symmetry preserve matter but not the gauge field?** Asked differently, **what is the ultimate criteria for some transformation to be a qualified one-form symmetry?**

Comment: I would think the most important property is how the transformation acts on Wilson lines.

Comment: @ConnorBehan right I guess you are right, "higher form symmetry" acts on "extended objects". Maybe the presence of matter changes the set of line operators, therefore affecting the allowed one-form symmetry. But at the moment I fail to make it more concrete.